# Wrapping array operation into a function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

The input `X` to my network has the shape `(10, 1, 5, 4)`. I am interested in boxplotting the distribution of input features (four), for each class. So, for example:

```
X = np.random.randn(10, 1, 5, 4)
a = np.zeros(5, dtype=int)
b = np.ones(5, dtype=int)
y = np.hstack((a,b))

print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
(10, 1, 5, 4)
(10,)
```

Then I separate the input `X`into respective classes, like:

```
class0, class1 =[],[]
for i in range(len(y)):
  if y[i]==0:
    class0.append(X[i])
  else:
    class1.append(X[i])


class0 = np.array(class0)
class1 = np.array(class1)
```

Taking `class0`into consideration, I can go ahead to manipulate it in a way that the four features are arranged per column (`col1, col2,col3,col4`) this way.

```
def transformer(myclass):
  #reshape  the class
  k = myclass.transpose((0,1,3,2))
  #access individual feature
  s = k[0][:,0].reshape(-1,1)
  a = k[0][:,1].reshape(-1,1)
  j = k[0][:, 2].reshape(-1,1)
  b = k[0][:, 3].reshape(-1,1)
  rslt = [s,a,j,b]
  return rslt
```

Then plot the features:

```
sns.boxplot(data=transformer(class0))
```

[image]

This is the general idea of my workflow. Note that the function `transformer` is hardcoded to access only the first observation (element) of the class it takes as input.

**Question:** How to I do modify my function to access all observations of the class, not per every single example, for generalised. Such that `col1`are all features in the class that are in first column for each example.

Do write the following:

```
def mytransformer(myclass):
  #first, transpose class
  k = myclass.transpose((0,1,3,2))
  #speed
  for i in range(k):
    s = k[i][:,0].reshape(-1,1)
  return s
```

Which gives the error:

```
mytransformer(class0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-5451e55f03d9> in <module>()
----> 1 mytransformer(class0)

<ipython-input-14-d1a2c8098caf> in mytransformer(myclass)
      3   myclass = myclass.transpose((0,1,3,2))
      4   #speed
----> 5   for i in range(myclass):
      6     s = k[i][:,0].reshape(-1,1)
      7   return s

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

2. Is there a way to add legend to the boxplot so that I can give name to each feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Question 1, You are using for loop range with a NumPy array which instead should have argument as an integer.

Maybe it is,

```
for i in range(len(k)):
```